# Error al definir atributo

Tags: xsd

Buenas estoy haciendo un ejercicio de pasar xlm a xsd. El xsd valida correctamente solo da error en el atributo y no se porque esta mal. Y mis apuntes pues son bastante pobres.
Este es el error

```
Referenced entity at "nbres:/org/netbeans/modules/xml/catalog/resources/datatypes.dtd".
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Se ha encontrado contenido no válido a partir del elemento 'atribute'. Se esperaba uno de '{"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":simpleType, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":complexType, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":group, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":attributeGroup, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":element, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":attribute, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":notation, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":annotation}'. [31] 
cvc-complex-type.4: El atributo 'name' debe aparecer en el elemento 'xs:simpleType'. [32] 
XML validation finished.
```

este es el xsd

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="alumno">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="direccion" type="tdireccion" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
                <xs:element name="telefono"  type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="tdireccion">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="calle" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="numero" type="infonumero"/>
            <xs:element name="ciudad" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="provincia" type="infoprovincia"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="infonumero">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="500"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="infoprovincia">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="caceres|badajoz"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <atribute name="dni">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{8}[A-Z]" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType> 
    </atribute>
</xs:schema>
```

A ver si me podeis decir el porque del error, no os pongo xlm por problemas de espacio porque me va decir que tengo demasiado codigo.

Comment: Estaría bien tener el XML. Intenta subirlo de alguna otra forma si es posible. Aunque sea visualizando el archivo desde algún sitio, así podría ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!Buenas!

A falta del **XML**, he intentado mirar el **XSD** que tienes, y he visto un par de errores.

**Primero**

> El atributo lo tienes mal escrito, no es atribute. Sino, `attribute`.

**Segundo**

> Tienes mal definido en la estructura el atributo. Te falta el `xs:` delante de la apertura y cierra del atributo. Quedando de esta forma: `xs:attribute`

Tu **código** quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="alumno">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="direccion" type="tdireccion" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
                <xs:element name="telefono"  type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="tdireccion">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="calle" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="numero" type="infonumero"/>
            <xs:element name="ciudad" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="provincia" type="infoprovincia"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="infonumero">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="500"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="infoprovincia">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="caceres|badajoz"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:attribute name="dni">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{8}[A-Z]" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType> 
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:schema>
```

Prueba el **XSD** ahora y me comentas.

Comment: ahora si perfecto muchas gracias ese era el error